# Statically linking a fortran mpi parallel program

Tags: fortran, mpi, static-linking

I'm trying to statically link the Nasa Parallel Benchmarks (NPB). My goal is to avoid installing the fortran compiler (mpif77) on the cluster nodes.

I don't see any static linking options in the mpif77 documentation.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? mpif77 is not a compiler, just a wrapper to the real thing.

Comment: In addition, I do not recall having seen that "wrapper" not been implemented as a script, so that'd be easy to patch accordingly. And in general - why run-time dynamic linking to shared libs would require the presence of the "compiler" on the nodes does not disclose itself to me.

Comment: @Solkar, the wrappers in Open MPI are C++ programs and not scripts.

Comment: @VladimirF using gfortran  

tried to add:
    -static to FLINKFLAGS

then I got /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi

then tried:
    MPI_LIB  = -L/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/current/lib64 -lmpi

and got the same

Comment: And which MPI implementation?

Comment: @VladimirF Open MPI 1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

OpenMPI can be built as a static library. Try linking with `-static`. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gfortran/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary for more options.

See http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#static-build if the static library is not built and contact your tech support or do it yourself if you are an admin.